# how to get symbol from money gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, currency

I am using money gem to represent money fields in my Product model.
Here's my code:

**Product model:**

```
          composed_of :price, 
          :class_name => "Money",
          :mapping => [%w(price cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
          :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) },
          :converter => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money : raise(ArgumentError, "Can't convert #{value.class} to Money") }
```

- I have fields like currency as string and price as string in my model.

I my **form view**:

```
 <li>
  <%= f.select(:currency,all_currencies(Money::Currency::TABLE), {:include_blank => 'Select a Currency'}, :class => "styled" )%>
 </li>
```

In my **Products helper**

```
def all_currencies(hash)
    hash.inject([]) do |array, (id, attributes)|
      array ||= []
      array << [attributes[:name], attributes[:iso_code]]
      array
    end
  end
```

- When I try to print product.currency in my view, I get the correct currency.For example for indian rupees, I get INR.But I dont know how to get symbol out of it.
- I tried using product.symbol as well as product.currency.symbol but I get "undefined method symbol"

Any help is deeply appreciated.

=====Solution:====

Inside my helper method,I needed to get [:symbol] attribute in the array..

```
def all_currencies(hash)
    hash.inject([]) do |array, (id, attributes)|
      array ||= []
      array << [attributes[:name], attributes[:iso_code],attributes[:symbol]]
      array
    end
  end
```

Comment: By symbol do you mean $ for dollar and similarly for INR ?

Comment: yes right....but i solved the problem

Comment: @AnidhyaAhuja Can you please mention how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @SwatiAggarwal the solution is mentioned just below the question.I had to get the symbol along with other attributes in the helper.